# Move Joins from entity to sub class

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
class Student {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumns({
          @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
  @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
  private Set<Subject> subjects;
}
```

I want to fetch only list of students, without fetching the set of subjects.
FetchType.LAZY didn't work as expected.

How can we solve this with the help of inheritance to fetch ONLY set of students or any other approach to do this.
We are using spring boot + jpa + mysql.

Comment: How will inheritance help you here? Remove @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN): http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/ "The “join” fetching strategy will disabled the lazy loading of all it’s related collections"

Comment: Thanks. It worked.